# Apparently Chrome doesn't think 0 is a number?

Tags: html, google-chrome, chromium

Let's have a look at this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='test'>
            <input type='number' min='0' max='255' step='10' name='testValue' value='50'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, it's a field that should accept any number from 0 to 255, right? Well, not exactly.

In Chrome 21.0.1155.2, you can enter anything in this field, but entering anything less than zero or over 255 will result in not being able to submit the form. The only exception is that **if you enter 0, the value will return to whatever it was before you changed it**. Here, try this yourself: http://pastehtml.com/raw/c05v9ofph.html

Is this a bug in Chrome or am I missing something?

Comment: No bug on Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m

Comment: samsamX: you mean, you can enter 0 and then click anywhere outside the input box and the value still stays 0? I guess this is a bug in Chrome that I should probably report, then.

Comment: Yes I can, but I also can do it for any value. And when I validate the form, out of range values provokes a popup display, but 0 works fine

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug here. Chrome 19.0.1084.52. Form pops up a warning for anything outside of the range, but submitting `0` (and also `-0`, as Registered User mentioned) just works. Clicking outside of the `<input>` does not reset it to a different value.

Comment: That's weird. I've disabled all of my extensions and still can't set the value to 0. Either there's a problem with my computer, or this is a bug introduced in Chrome 20 or 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a confirmed bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130910).

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome and I have no problem submitting 0

What else I found is that it allows me to submit -0 as it is shown in the address bar upon submit.

This means that you have a bug in your code which uses int as string.